# After updating I am getting a number of errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-graph-api

I updated to xcode 7.3, but I am getting a ton of errors. Main one is the facebook  sdk. Below is my code. I am getting the error `Ambiguous use of 'subscript'`.

```
userDetails.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection, result, error: NSError!)-> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if(result != nil){
            //error is for every line below userId-userBirthday
            let userId: String = result["id"] as! String
            let userFirstName: String? = result["first_name"] as? String
            let userLastName: String? = result["last_name"] as? String
            let userEmail: String? = result["email"] as? String
            let userBirthday: String? = result["birthday"] as? String

     }
}
```

Comment: You should tell which line gives you the error.

Comment: I did I indicated that I get the lines with the instantiations of userId-userBirthday, it is commented out

Comment: didn't notice the comment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With latest FBSDK, the completionHandler: has been changed.

Let take a look at this as below:

let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: param)

graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { [weak self] connection, result, 
error in

```
 if error != nil {

      //onError()

      print(error.description)

      return

 }else{

      let fbResult = result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
      //Do You rest of the code here
 }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

This is because Xcode doesn't know that the result is a NSDictionary, try this instead:

```
let dic:NSDictionary = result

if(dic != nil){
        let userId: String = dic["id"] as! String
}
```